# How do I htaccess redirect all my urls containing %23 replacing this with #

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect all my urls replacing %23 with a # in my htaccess file

Example: http://afdelingtest.nl/vierdaagsefeesten/programma/%23jaap-categorie should be http://afdelingtest.nl/vierdaagsefeesten/programma/#jaap-categorie

The last part 'jaap-categorie' differs.

I tried many example Htaccess lines but nothing seems to work. Like: RewriteRule ^(.#.) /$1 [R,NE]

Can somebody help me achieve this?

Best, Jaap

Comment: You can not. The `#` is not sent to the server.  Use javascript or other client side logic to redirect your fragment URL.

Answer (score 0):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/x4qmmX/1) might help you to write a RewriteRule and do so:

```
^(.*)(%23)(.*)$
```

The hex code for hashtag is `\x23`. You want to replace it with `$1\x23$3`. 
[image]

This graph shows how that expression would work:

[image]

Your RewriteRule might look like something similar to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(%23)(.*)$ $1\x23$3 [NE,R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(%23)(.*)$ $1\x23$3 [NE,R=302,L]
```

- 302 is temporary and 301 is permanent, however you wish. You might want to do a 302, then change it to 301.
- You might want to clear your browser cache every time you change your `.htaccess` file.
- I'm assuming that you have one `%23` in your URLs.

Comment: Hello i tried this but didn't get success 
i want to redirect 
 http://example.com/%23/dashboard  to http://example.com/#/dashboard
can you please help me to achieve this

Comment: @lochawala Make sure you use NE: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne